# Unable to resolve Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Error : Firebaseauth or firebasedatase in short all firebase dependicies are unable to resolve. 
Though everything is working perfectly even with this error but i can not be able to use intellisense of firebase.

```
Error picture
```

[image]

Comment: show us your dependencies in gradle file

Comment: Please add the content of your both build.gradle files and responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Have you tried "invalidate cache and restart" under File. Looks like you are using intellij so should be there

Comment: @Popeye Thanks !
it worked.

Comment: @PlumWater I've left an answer in that case

Answer (score 0):

Do you import FirebaseAuth in your gradle file ?

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
```

Comment: yes all dependencies are already implemented and Project is working fine regardless of this error. i think it has something to with IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency for Realtime Database to your app-level build.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suffer from this a lot at work (I usually blame the company proxy getting in the way), what normally resolves this though is doing `Invalidate Caches/Restart` which can be found under `File`